# How can I search for a document whom a field contains a regex matches with the query?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, python-cloudant

I have a collection of documents with a field called "idPattern" containing regex string. I want to search all documents that their fields "idPattern" regex string matches with my search string or a substring of it. How can I perform it?

Example:

Document:

```
{
"_id":....,
"_rev":....,
"idPattern":"*"
},
{
"_id":....,
"_rev":....,
"idPattern":"park"
},
{
"_id":....,
"_rev":....,
"idPattern":"stree*"
}
```

Search by: `"park_central"`

The first two documents should be returned.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your intent is. You want to always search for `_id:******` etc? Are they comma separated? Do you know how many digits each are? How are you determining which capture group you want to capture?

Comment: idPattern isn't about _id.

For example, we have this query:

{"id": {"$regex": "regular_expression"}}

I will search using a regular expression and it will return all elements their fields called id matches the regex.

I want something inverse of it. The regex stays in the field, and it should match with my search.

Comment: What do you mean by by saying "I want something inverse of it"? It would be helpful to show what you've tried (query selector for example).  Is this a `couchdb` question or a `regex` question?